# apache service is not found even that i installed it

Tags: java, apache, apache2, windows-server-2003

#### my problem

i have a windows server 2003. I develop a java server. I want to run this java server on my windows server 2003. I downloaded apache tomcat 7 and i unzip it. then i start it from the bin folder. i put the war file of my server on the workapp folder of tomcat and finally my java server is working perfectly on my windows server 2003.

the problem is when i log of from my account on the windows server 2003, the apache tomcat stops and there is nothing wrong with this since i log off and all the process will stop.

i want to keep my java server running even when i log off **(note that i log off not shut down the server)** i searched the internet and i found that i have to install the apache service on my windows server 2003. i go and download the `httpd-2.0.65-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y.msi` file from the official apache website. i installed it. however **i didn't find the apache service on my services.**

#### Note that can be help

I already have IIS installed on my windows server 2003

any help will be appreciatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer mysefl.
it is because the same port is running on IIS.
just change the `listen` second on the configuration file to another port and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have to install an enable-it :

1. Go to your `bin` dir of your apache installation folder with the windows console
2. Install the service by executing this command in the console : `httpd.exe -k install -n "Apache"`.
3. Then, start the service : `httpd.exe -k start -n "Apache"`
4. The service will start and auto-start :

[image: Apache service]

The process is started under the `LocalSystem` account, so it will keep running if you logoff.

If you want more information : [Using Apache on Microsoft Windows](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/platform/windows.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run Java web application in *war* format (running on servlet container), then you should install **Apache Tomcat** (not httpd Apache!) as service. You can download latest tomcat from [here](http://ftp.piotrkosoft.net/pub/mirrors/ftp.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.47/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.47.exe).